# Backbone JS Handle Save Model?

Tags: backbone.js

Using Backbone I can `fetch` the Collection like below and render a Backbone View for each record:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Person,
    url: '/home/people/'
});
```

When I spin up a new person using Backbone like below, isn't it supposed to already handle the .save() functionality by posting to the URL defined in the above collection?

```
var p = new Person({ Name: 'Andrew', Age: 24 });
p.save();
// Uncaught Error: A 'url' property or function must be specified
// I thought it was supposed to use the Collection's URL?
// I can get around this by explicitly setting p.URL but doesn't seem right
```

Comment: When you rely on the collection url, your Person must be included in that collection before you issuing a save... otherwise backbone as no way to know what the url is.

Comment: you realise you can set the `collection` on your `Model.extend` call and it will get the `url` from the collection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like an approach is to use the current collection and `create` which handles adding it to the collection and saving it

```
this.people.create(p);
```

The source is below.  Create is off the collection, so it sets the Models collection to `this`  Then once the Save it success it adds Model to your collection.  So it passes the model to getUrl, the getUrl looks at the URL property on the model, which in turn passes the collection to getUrl again... that way we don't have to redefine URL...

```
create : function(model, options) {
  var coll = this;
  options || (options = {});
  if (!(model instanceof Backbone.Model)) {
    model = new this.model(model, {collection: coll});
  } else {
    model.collection = coll;
  }
  var success = function(nextModel, resp) {
    coll.add(nextModel);
    if (options.success) options.success(nextModel, resp);
  };
  return model.save(null, {success : success, error : options.error});
},
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just set the collection

`Person.collection = PersonCollection`

Now it will magically know the url.

Answer (score 5):

According to the backbone.js code in Backbone.sync, this does not seem like the case.  Perhaps the documentation is old or not correct.  The code reads:

```
// Helper function to get a URL from a Model or Collection as a property
// or as a function.
var getUrl = function(object) {
  if (!(object && object.url)) throw new Error("A 'url' property or function must be specified");
  return _.isFunction(object.url) ? object.url() : object.url;
};
```

which suggests to me that the model needs its own url.  So you should just do this:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    if (this.isNew()) return '/home/people/';
    return '/home/whatever-this-route-would-be';
  }
});
```